# Use of 'that' in 'The morality of Buddhism is essentially that of the Upanishads except in the matter of forbidding sacrifice.'

Tags: conjunctions, that

Could anyone help me understand the use of 'that' in the below sentence? (I took this example from an old book)

> The morality of Buddhism is essentially that of the Upanishads except in the matter of forbidding sacrifice.

What is the role of that in the above sentence?

Comment: I'd like to see how research could solve the problem of anaphoric reference. Why the close votes?

Comment: Using "that" as a pronoun is a straightforward feature of English that's in every grammar book. Unless the OP can explain their problem in more detail, closure seems reasonable and in accordance with rules.

Answer (score 3):

"That of" is a fairly common, albeit somewhat formal, phrase. As well as "those of."

In it, the *that* part stands for the previously used noun.

Therefore:

> The morality of Buddhism is essentially that of the Upanishads except
> in the matter of forbidding sacrifice.

... can be read as:

> The morality of Buddhism is essentially **the morality** of the Upanishads except
> in the matter of forbidding sacrifice.

Consider:

> The compositional methods of the Golden Age of Operetta closely
> resemble **those of** Verismo composers.

Which you can read as:

> The compositional methods of the Golden Age of Operetta closely
> resemble the compositional methods of Verismo composers.

You can think of "that of" or "those of" as "belonging to."

Comment: Thank you @Ricky

Comment: @nityananthanmurugan: My pleasure.

Comment: @nityananthanmurugan - if it's completely answered your question, consider accepting the answer by pressing the checkmark :)

Comment: @Heartspring: We're not here for the glory.

Comment: Perhaps not, and sorry if I crossed a boundary, but it'd also help future visitors to know that it is _the_ answer. (Which it is, in my view.)

Comment: @Heartspring: You didn't cross any boundaries. I just couldn't help myself. This is fun!

Comment: @Heartspring: I don't do emoticons, is all.